# Is it possible to define Example table and pass the entire table as data to the step definition argument?

Tags: bdd, cucumber-java

taking an example of a simple feature outline:

```
Scenario Outline: Example Table Experiment
Given User Does Something with **{ExampleTable}**

Examples:
|   Key1   |   Key2   |   Key3   |
|Key1-Vaue1|Key2-Vaue1|Key3-Vaue1|
|Key1-Vaue2|Key2-Vaue2|Key3-Vaue2|
|Key1-Vaue3|Key2-Vaue3|Key3-Vaue3|
```

And then on the Step definition side, we have something like:

```
    @When("^User Does Something with$")
    public void user_does_something_with_DataTables_asMap(**ExamplTable et**) {
       //code to extract values from example table
    
    }
```

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using a vertical-oriented data table. Column 1 would contain the keys, and column 2 would contain the values. You will need a token in the value column for each column in your examples table:

```
Scenario Outline: Example Table Experiment
    Given User Does Something with
        | Key  | Value  |
        | Key1 | <Key1> |
        | Key2 | <Key2> |
        | Key3 | <Key3> |

Examples:
    |   Key1   |   Key2   |   Key3   |
    |Key1-Vaue1|Key2-Vaue1|Key3-Vaue1|
    |Key1-Vaue2|Key2-Vaue2|Key3-Vaue2|
    |Key1-Vaue3|Key2-Vaue3|Key3-Vaue3|
```

The step definition would receive a single DataTable parameter.